# Orientation issues in the webview after zooming in Iphone?

Tags: iphone

I am loading a pdf file in my resource to a webview which is a subview of a UIView. It's working fine in all orientations. But when I zoom in and out once, then the landscape width is not getting to the pdf. The pdf file is still showing in the size of portrait mode..Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call reload method on UIWebView object after some time to reload the webview in shouldautorotate method of the view controller.

The only problem with this approach will be that the pdf file will scroll back to the first page(May be).

But you can always use a third party library to display pdf files as uiwebview will not work with the pdf files larger than 10 MB. As it loads the hole pdf file into the memory.

These are some links for displaying pdf files in ios devices.

http://fastpdfkit.com/
https://github.com/vfr/Reader